# Пре-событие перед удалением мобильного приложения

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Мне нужно отловить событие удаления приложения с устройства, что бы разлогинить пользователя, не могу найти актуальную информацию. Нашел под java за 2014 год. Дайте хлебных крошек куда копать.

Comment: Что именно вы нашли? Вообще пишут, что это недоспустимо и если и возможно, то на очень старых андройдах, так как является нарушением безопасности. Так что можете считать что то что вам нужно, сделать невозможно.

Comment: @aepot поделитесь опытом или best practice, как правильно реализовать логику? Мне нужно завершать сессию юзера если он удалил приложение. Пока идея только мониторить последнею активность пользователя и если она > чем N завершать сессию. Спасибо за ответ, по xamarin очень мало отвечают и дают советы.

Comment: Вообще сессия юзера - это некий токен, который выдан приложению, чтобы оно общалось с сервером, получая данные, предназначенные для конкретного пользователя. Время жизни токена может быть любое. Наличие токена у пользователя не должно означать, что он онлайн или доступен. Сам токен может жить долго, например несколько месяцев, зависит от того, как часто вы хотите предлагать юзеру перелогиниться. Токен конечно же можно продлевать, например если ему осталось меньше месяца, то продлить еще на 3 месяца. Либо просто считать несколько месяцев от последнего использования. Разлогин - удаление токена.

Comment: Присутствие пользователя онлайн - это время от последнего обмена данными с сервером, это может быть интервал в несколько минут или в час, время жизни токена в флаге присутствия онлайн никак не учитывается. Да, забыл уточнить, токен должен быть уникален на каждое устройство, у пользователя может быть много токенов. То есть если у него 2 телефона, то на каждый свой уникальный токен.